# h2:first-child and h2:first-type does not work as I expected

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm having trouble with h2:first-child and h2:first-of-type

```
h1,
h2 {
  color: #1098ad;
}
h2:first-of-type {
  color: #444;
}
```

All the h2 are colored with #444 but when write the h2:first-child or h2:first-of-type overwrites all the h2 and I don't know why.
Also when I leave it like this:

> ```
> h1
> {
>   color: #1098ad;
> }
> h2:first-of-type {
>   color: #444;
> }
> ```

The h2:firs-of-type and the h2:first-child color all the h2.
Here is my code (sorry if it is a bit long)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  color: #000;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 40px;
}

.options {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.description {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

h1,
h2 {
  color: #1098ad;
}

h2:first-of-type {
  color: #444;
}

article {
  flex: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

aside h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

aside {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  border-top: 5px solid #83989b;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #83989b;
  align-self: flex-start;
  flex: 0 0 230px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>My web page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="main-header">
      <h1>gomen</h1>
      <nav class="options">
        <a href="#profile">Profile</a>
        <a href="#hobbies">Hobbies</a>
        <a href="#goals">Goals</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
      <article>
        <h2 class="first-child">A little bit about me</h2>
        <section class="profile">
          <h2 id="profile">Profile</h2>
          <div class="description">
            <img src="me.jpeg" alt="owner" height="80" />
          </div>
        </section>
        <section>
          <h2 id="hobbies">Hobbies</h2>
        </section>
        <section>
          <h2 id="goals">Goals</h2>
        </section>
      </article>
      <aside>
        <section>
          <h2 id="contacto">Contact</h2>
        </section>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2021 by gomen.</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please add your html

Comment: your html is needed

Comment: I already added it, thanks

Comment: All your h2 are first-of-type - e.g. first h2 in a section. You need more specificity. Which h2s do you actually want to change the color of?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:first-of-type is working correctly in your code.

h2:first-of-type would be the first h2 child of each parent element, not the first h2 throughout the whole document.

```css
h2 {
  color: blue;
}

h2:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h2>This is the first h2 type in body</h2>
    <h2>This is the second h2 type in body</h2>
    <div>
      <h2>This is the first h2 type in div</h2>
      <h2>This is the second h2 type in div</h2>
    </div>
    <h2>This is the third h2 type in body</h2>
  </body>
```

You will need to isolate it to just h2 elements in article elements.

```css
article > h2:first-of-type {
  color: #444;
}
```